# Manual animation for non-animatable UI elements

Tags: ios, core-animation, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to animate UI elements that are not supported by `animateWithDuration:animations:` and can't be animated by a transition.

First thing that comes to mind is doing something like this:

```
_animationStartDate = [NSDate date];
[self performSelector:@selector(manualAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0/MYManualAnimationFrameRate];

- (void)manualAnimation
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:_animationStartDate];
    CGFloat progress = interval / MYManualAnimationDuration;
    if (progress < 1)
    {
        [self setValuesOfManualAnimationAtProgress:progress];
        [self performSelector:@selector(manualAnimation:) withObject:number afterDelay:1.0/MYManualAnimationFrameRate];
    } else {
        [self setValuesOfManualAnimationAtProgress:1];
    }
}
```

Before reinventing the wheel, is there any API for these kinds of animations?

If not, anything else I should take into account (e.g., calling `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` in `dealloc`, dynamic frame rate)? Would I gain something by using GCD?

Comment: In case you're wondering, I'm animating `NSTextAttachment` properties.

Comment: If you are going to do a manual animation like that, please use a CADisplayLink.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist D'oh. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before reinventing the wheel, is there any API for these kinds of animations?

That would be [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) which "is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display"

You use it to call a selector with this signature whenever it's time to redraw

```
- (void) selector:(CADisplayLink *)sender;
```

In your drawing code you can use the `timestamp` of the display link to know how far into the animation to draw.